# Configuring web.xml to execute particular Page

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml

I am having a Login.jsp page in Admin Folder. Now when ever the user access the Admin folder the Login Page should be the first to get Executed.

Below is my Directory structure for Project.

[image]

How to Configure in web.xml so that when i access the Admin folder Login.jsp will be executed instead of index.jsp

The contents of web.xml is as given below

```
<display-name>RealCMS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: you don't let your user access the Admin folder, do you? If not, just expose the link to login.jsp wherever required or have a check in the filter to see if the user is already logged in and then redirect the user to the appropriate page.

Comment: Try adding Login.jsp to the welcome-file list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as I think you shouldn't provide direct access to user for your admin folder.
Rather than doing this you can do mapping for all jsp pages in admin folder.
If this is a simple application without any framework you can simply configure all jsp pages in web.xml to map against appropriate urls. In case of using frameworks like struts you can use modules configuration.

As per your question try this.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```